# Class variable in XCTestCase in Objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, unit-testing

This is my code:

```
#import <XCTest/XCTest.h>
#import "GTN_GameStatistics.h"


@interface GTN_GameStatisticsTest : XCTestCase

@end

@implementation GTN_GameStatisticsTest{
   GTN_GameStatistics * _gameStatistic;
}

+ (void)setUp
{
    [super setUp];
    // Put setup code here; it will be run once, before the first test case.

}

- (void)setUp
{
    [super setUp];
    // Put setup code here; it will be run once, before the first test case.

    _gameStatistic = [GTN_GameStatistics sharedManager]; 
}

- (void)tearDown
{
    // Put teardown code here; it will be run once, after the last test case.
    [super tearDown];

    [_gameStatistic resetStatistics];
}
```

Is there some way to put code from `- (void)setUp` to + `(void)setUp`.
For that I need to make `GTN_GameStatistics * _gameStatistic` a class variable not instance variable, but I do not know how.
I tried few way but it did not work.
I can do it with out it , but would like to know is it possible and how ?

Comment: Please use the `xcode` tag only for questions related to the IDE itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as a "class variable" but a global variable does the trick.  Below your #imports:

```
static GTN_GameStatistics * _gameStatistic;
```

Then in your +setup method:

```
_gameStatistic = [GTN_GameStatistics sharedManager];
```

Comment: C++ have it, so I thought that objective-c, also have it.